# SQL Pivot "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'."

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am new at using Pivot in SQL and ran into some trouble.

I constantly keep getting an error, when i try to embed a pivot table to my Select-query, and despite hours of reading several webpages I cant seem to figure it out.

I am working on a dashboard-db, which will contain several pivot-tables (5) in the query, one for each Dashboard. is this possible?

**The error I'm getting is :**

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT 
    /* Query for dashboard 1 **/
    [ProjectUID] AS [Project UID],
    [ + 8 Regular selects not related to the pivot  ]

    /* Query for dashboard 2 **/
    [...]

        /* Query for dashboard 3 **/
    [...]

        /* Dashboard WOWs */
    (SELECT * FROM [PB_Customer])
    PIVOT
        (
            COUNT (MValue) 
            for MValue
                in (
                [Customer],
                [MNeeds],
                [Bousa],
                [backbook]
                )
        ) AS pvt_table_wow

    FROM    [Table 1], [Table 2], [Table 3] 

    WHERE   Table1.ProjectUID=.Table2PROJECTUID 
            AND Table2.[Ping] IS NOT NULL 
            AND Table2.[Bousa] NOT IN ('0')
            AND Table1.ProjectUID=Table3.PUID;
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can't use `*` in pivot.  You will need to specify the column names and alias -- look at this -> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Just from what you showed, there should be a FROM before the /* Dash board WOWs */. Specifically where, is depended on the query. Check this out. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: you aren't aliasing your sub-query above it, but perhaps that is or isn't supposed to be a sub query it's hard to tell since you have another FROM and WHERE clause below the pivot... post all of your code and it could shed some light.

Comment: You can't have a subquery in the SELECT clause return more than one column and more than one row. Other than that, what you probably wanted to write is `(SELECT * FROM [PB_Customer] PIVOT (...) AS pvt_table_wow)` but as I said that won't work.

Comment: @Hogan while it's best practice not to, there isn't anything incorrect about using *... except i'm not sure if that' supposed to be a sub query or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must alias a sub-queries

change

```
(SELECT * FROM [PB_Customer]) PIVOT
```

to

```
(SELECT * FROM [PB_Customer]) c PIVOT
```

Comment: that doesn't work. Downvote

Comment: @pianocomposer, have you seen the question? I hope you didn't try to run it As Is.